# Xamarin Fragment Switching in Adapter

Tags: android, xamarin

Replacing fragment in xamarin android on click of button but I'm not able to switch my fragment with other fragment in adapter class.

```
swagBtn.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var events = new Events();
    var BaseFragments = new BaseFragments();

    BaseFragments.FragmentReplaceWithOutBackstak(
        "",
        Resource.Id.main_container,
        events,
        Resource.Animator.enter,
        Resource.Animator.exit,
        Resource.Animator.pop_enter,
        Resource.Animator.pop_exit
    );
};
```

Here is the FragmentReplaceWithOutBackstak method

```
public void FragmentReplaceWithOutBackstak(
    String str,
    int continer,
    Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment Class,
    int anim_first,
    int anim_second,
    int anim_third,
    int anim_fourth
)
{
    Activity.SupportFragmentManager
        .BeginTransaction()
        .SetCustomAnimations(anim_first, anim_second, anim_third, anim_fourth)
        .Replace(continer, Class)
        .Commit();
}
```

Comment: You need to show you've tried to resolve your problem yourself. What have you tried? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: swagBtn.Click+= delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   var events = new Events ();                 var BaseFragments =new BaseFragments();     BaseFragments.FragmentReplaceWithOutBackstak("", Resource.Id.main_container, events, Resource.Animator.enter, Resource.Animator.exit, Resource.Animator.pop_enter,     Resource.Animator.pop_exit);       };

Comment: Its function in base fragment class public void FragmentReplaceWithOutBackstak(String str, int continer, Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment Class , int anim_first,
   int anim_second, int anim_third, int anim_fourth) {
   Activity.SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction()
   .SetCustomAnimations(anim_first, anim_second, anim_third,
   anim_fourth).Replace(continer, Class).Commit(); 

  }

Comment: I've added your code examples to your question as they are better suited there than as comments.

Comment: Thanks Tom you know how to resolved it?